# Polygon made up of 12 unit sticks with an area limit

Tags: geometry, logic, puzzle

A polygon is made up of 12 unit sticks and its area is 3 units^2. Find as many such polygons as possible. Note that a side of the polygon could be made up of more than 1 stick but a stick could not be cut/bent.

Comment: There are infinitely many such polygons. Imagine you have a regular hexagon with unit sides. It has area $\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} \sim 2.598$. If you are holding 2 opposite vertices of the hexagon and pull them slowly apart. You will continuously deform the hexagon and reduces its area to 0. This means if you build up your 12-gon using 2 hexagons joining at a vertex. There are infinitely many ways to match up the area of the 2 hexagons to get the number 3. Is there more constraint on your 12-gons?

Comment: do you have any other figure that is easy to construct and have proof that the area would be 3? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Consider unit shapes such as
1. 3,4,5 triangle
2. Squares
3. Equilateral triangles
4. diamonds whose area + equilateral area = 1
5. 6 pointed stars

From 1, you'll need to remove 3 squares, easily done.
For the 2 trominos, they both use 8 matches.  Substitute 2 in and 2 out equi-triangles
For the 5 tetrominos, you'll need to skew a square into a diamond, and then subtract a triangle.

There are more shapes, but they get more irregular.

Comment: I don't really get what do you mean by the 2 trominos. Could you like attach a diagram? Please also include a diagram for your unit shapes 2, 3, and 4. Thanks. Could you find more such polygons, I am just curious...

Comment: [Tromino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino). 2=A square of 4 matches and 3=a triangle of 3 matches.

Comment: how would the area be 3 in this case? Note that it is a polygon. How could each of the figures be constructed? Could you show a picture?

Comment: Please help me by giving examples on the shapes 2, 3, 4. I think a picture could help a lot. Do you have any other suitable figures that have an easy proof on why the area would be 3?